tailwind not working with nextjs, shadcn components
I have a NextJS project using shadcn-ui components, but after adding tailwindCSS, none of the styling shows up when trying classnames.
I have configured the components.json, tailwind.config.ts, and globals.css files correctly(I think). but no matter how much I delete node modules and re-run 'npm install', the styling does not show up. I only  have one of each file for the record.
File structure:
globals.css is in the app folder, and imported in the layout file(though no auto-complete when entering the import)

globals.css:
tailwind imports

Tailwind.config.ts:
Content paths all included.

components.json:
tailwind config and globals files included.

Package.json:


Have you import your global.css to your layout.tsx ?

@cantdocpp Yes, I have "import './globals.css'" in my layout.tsx file

Did you install Tailwind manually? If so, did you follow the official guide?

Show me your package.json

@cantdocpp Just added it

I want to see your layout.tsx

You've installed Sass but not PostCSS. If you want to use Tailwind's JIT mode (recommended), you'll need to install PostCSS. The official recommendation is not to use Sass or other preprocessors, but if you insist, check out this documentation.

@KarsonJo Ah so they do not work together, Ill check out the docs, thanks!

Yes, they recommend and support using PostCSS. Honestly, I've looked through their documentation and there isn't specific guidance on how to configure Sass. However, there's another section that suggests a method using PostCSS plugins to achieve similar effects to Sass.

in your tailwind.config.ts, change your content to -
"./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",

